# Referential constraint violation

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Normally for this message there will be a message, but i found there was no `MSGW` and job got terminated...what could be the reason?

> Cause . . . . . : The operation being performed on member &4 file &2 in library &3 failed. Constraint &16 prevents record number &17 from being inserted or updated in member &6 of dependent file &7 in library &8 because a matching key value was not found in member &18 of parent file &19 in library &20. If the record number is zero, then the error occurred on an insert operation. The constraint rule is &9. The constraint rules are:
> 1 -- *RESTRICT
>
> 2 -- *NOACTION
>
> Recovery . . . : Either specify a different file, change the file, or change the program. Then try your request again.
> Possible choices for replying to message . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
> C -- The request is canceled.
> I -- The request is ignored.

Comment: Sounds to me as if the message got answered automatically, do you have a relevant reply list entry in place and being activated, or some sort of console monitor handling such messages automatically? Or, more simply, is your program monitoring for errors and ignoring them?

Comment: Please include the message id and message type from the job log. This question only includes part of the message with none of the replacement fields filled in. Which constraint rule is violated? Did something monitor for this and send it as an escape message?

Comment: Some types of jobs (e.g. CGI) may auto-answer unhandled exceptions.